# How to add a css file like materialize in popup.js of chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, google-chrome-extension

Actually i am making a chrome extension, I have added a materialize css for popup.html and works properly when added a button in popup.html but now i want to append a button which has a materialize css style from popup.js.

Basically i want to have a materialize style while appending anything from js file.
I have tried:

popup.html-

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css" media="screen,projection"/>
```

Code which i have tried is in(popup.js):

```
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css" type="text/css" />'); 
$("#demo").append("<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">button</a>");
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: `"<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">button</a>"` is invalid syntax. Use different types of quotes inside and outside. Also check the popup's console for errors: rightclick the popup, then `Inspect`.